Keep main branch only on GitLab project from group template
What I am trying to do
To create a new project using a Group-level template that copies only the main branch , via GitLab API.
What I did
(On GitLab Ultimate/Enterprise)

Use FetchAPI to send a POST request  (success)
to GitLab Projects API to create a new project (success)
using a Group-level template (success)
that copies only the main branch. (fails - copies all branches into new project)

Repl code only
    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('PRIVATE-TOKEN', `${GITLAB_TOKEN}`);
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    const createProjectBody = JSON.stringify({
        name: `${NAME}`,
        description: `generated from template`,
        namespace_id: `${GROUPS_ID}`,
        use_custom_template: true,
        group_with_project_templates_id: `${TEMPLATE_GROUP_ID}`,
        template_project_id: `${TEMPLATE_ID}`
    });

    fetch(`${PROJECTS_URL}`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: headers,
        body: createProjectBody,
    }).then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
            console.log('Project created');
        } else {
            console.log('Error creating project');
        }
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
    });

What I tried

use_custom_template: false, changing true to false

response 400 Bad Request: '' not a valid template_name


add template_name: ${TEMPLATE_NAME}

response 400 Bad Request: template_project_id and template_name are mutually exclusive


keep template_name and remove template_project_id

response 400 Bad Request: 'mytemplate' is unknown or invalid




Did you know that \${VARIABLE}`andVARIABLEare exactly the same ifVARIABLE` is already a string?

yes, but I use ${VARIABLE} to handle any async cases where VARIABLE may be unresolved/undefined. I simplified code for my question
